# Read csv files in a loop, isolating the non-empty elements from a specific column each time-Python

Tags: python, csv

I am new to Python and I attempt to read .csv files sequentially in a for or while loop (I have about 250 .csv). The aim is to read each .csv file and isolate only all the columns, whenever a specific column (let's call it "wanted_column") is non-empty (i.e. its non-empty rows). Then, save all the non-empty rows of the "wanted_column", as well as all its columns, in a new .csv file.

Hence, at the end, I want to have 250 .csv files with all columns for each row that has non-empty elements in the "wanted_column".

Hopefully this is clear. I would appreciate any ideas.

George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this code below just to give you an idea of how to do it. Beware that this code below does not check for any errors. Its behavior is undefined if one of your CSV files is empty, if it couldn't find the file, and if the column you defined is a none existence column in one of the file. There could be more. Thus, you would want to build a check code around it. Also, your CSV formatting could greatly be depended on python csv package.

So now to the code explanation. For the "paths" variable. You can give that a string, a tuple, or a list. If you give it a string, it will convert that to a tuple with one index. You can give that variable the file(s) that you want to work with.

For the "column" variable, that one should be a string. You need to build an error checking for that if needed.

For code routines, the function will read all the CSV files of the paths list. Each time it read a file, it will read the first line first and save the content to a variable(rowFields).

After that, it generates the dict header(fields) with key(column name) to value(position). That dict is used to search for the column position by using its name. For here, you could also go through each field and if the field matches the column name then you save that value as the column position. Then that position could later be used instead of keep on searching the dict for the position using the name. The later method described in this paragraph should be the fastest.

After that, it goes on and read each row of the CSV file until the end. Each time it read a row, it will check if the length of the string from the column that defined by the "column" variable is larger than zero. If that string length is larger than zero, then it will append that row to the variable contentRows.

After the function done reading the CSV file, it will write the contents of variable "rowFields" and "contentRows" to a CSV file that defined by the "outfile" variable. To make it easy for me, outfile simply equal to input file + ".new". You can just change that.

```
import csv

def getNoneEmpty( paths, column ):
  if isinstance(paths, str):
    paths = (paths, )
  if not isinstance(paths, list) and not isinstance(paths, tuple):
    raise("paths have to be a or string, list, or tuple")

  quotechar='"'
  delimiter=","
  lineterminator="\n"

  for f in paths:
    outfile = f + ".new" # change this area to how you want to generate the new file

    fields = {}
    rowFields = None
    contentRows = []

    with open(f, newline='') as csvfile:
      csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=delimiter, quotechar=quotechar, lineterminator=lineterminator)

      rowFields = next(csvReader)

      for i in range(0, len(rowFields)):
        fields[rowFields[i]] = i

      for row in csvReader:
        if len(row[fields[column]]) != 0:
          contentRows.append(row)

    with open(outfile, 'w') as csvfile:
      csvWriter = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=delimiter, quotechar=quotechar,quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, lineterminator=lineterminator)

      csvWriter.writerow(rowFields)
      csvWriter.writerows(contentRows)


getNoneEmpty(["test.csv","test2.csv"], "1958")
```

test.csv content:

```
"Month","1958","1959","1960"
"JAN",115,360,417
"FEB",318,342,391
"MAR",362,406,419
"APR",348,396,461
"MAY",11,420,472
"JUN",124,472,535
"JUL",158,548,622
"AUG",505,559,606
"SEP",404,463,508
"OCT",,407,461
"NOV",310,362,390
"DEC",110,405,432
```

test2.csv content:

```
"Month","1958","1959","1960"
"JAN",,360,417
"FEB",318,342,391
"MAR",362,406,419
"APR",348,396,461
"MAY",,420,472
"JUN",,472,535
"JUL",,548,622
"AUG",505,559,606
"SEP",404,463,508
"OCT",,407,461
"NOV",310,362,390
"DEC",110,405,432
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your useful input Kevin. I added my csv files under my current directory and defined the path as:                                                                                                    paths = "./"                                                                                                                        
The column is: column=['20201-2.0']

Comment: However, the code is running but not returning any new .csv files. Any ideas why this may happen?                                                                                           Going through your code, considering that I only need the rows that have non-empty cells for my "column", do I need the rowFields as well or just the contentRows?

Comment: @G.Papas - you are welcome and path has to be a list or tuple of file not the directory path itself. For example ["./abc.csv", "/something/atc.csv/", "some/other/path/jj.csv"]. It can also be a string to one file. Thus, you have to compose a list of files that you want to send to this function.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully it will work:

```
def main():

    temp = []
    with open(r'old_csv') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')

        for row in csv_reader:
            for x in row:
                temp.append(x)

    with open(r'new_csv', mode='w') as new_file:
        writer = csv.writer(new_file, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')

        for col in temp:
            list_ = col.split(',')
            writer.writerow(list_)
```